# zxing library not scanning QR code black background and white code(Negative scan) in android

Tags: android, zxing

In My application using zxing library for scanning QR code but library can't support scanning white in black code(Negative scan)  so please suggest me solution how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code, source.invert() will do your work

```
 LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmaps[0].getWidth(), 
 bitmaps[0].getHeight(), intArray);
 BinaryBitmap bMap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

        try {
            result = reader.decode(bMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            BinaryBitmap bMap1 = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source.invert()));
            try {
                result = reader.decode(bMap1);
            } catch (NotFoundException notFoundException) {
              //  notFoundException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ChecksumException checksumException) {
                //checksumException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException formatException) {
                //formatException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: But if I do this will it stop working in day mode?